# Download multiple files with CefSharp in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, cefsharp

How can I download multiple files using CefSharp.

I need to download multiple files from a page, I execute a javaScript to do this.
First, I prove in Chrome, and the beginning doesn't work, only download the first link. I fixed it changing the property **Automatic Downloads** to **Allow all sites to download multiple files automatically** on Chrome [Content Settings-Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hgmf1.png)

With CefSharp, first, I couldn't download anything, with this code I fixed it.

```
Public Class DownloadHandler
Implements IDownloadHandler

Public Event OnBeforeDownloadFired As EventHandler(Of DownloadItem)
Public Event OnDownloadUpdatedFired As EventHandler(Of DownloadItem)

Public Sub OnBeforeDownload(browser As IBrowser, downloadItem As DownloadItem, callback As IBeforeDownloadCallback) Implements IDownloadHandler.OnBeforeDownload
    RaiseEvent OnBeforeDownloadFired(Me, downloadItem)

    If Not callback.IsDisposed Then
        Using callback
            callback.[Continue](downloadItem.SuggestedFileName, showDialog:=False)
        End Using
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub OnDownloadUpdated(browser As IBrowser, downloadItem As DownloadItem, callback As IDownloadItemCallback) Implements IDownloadHandler.OnDownloadUpdated
    RaiseEvent OnDownloadUpdatedFired(Me, downloadItem)
End Sub
End Class
```

But my problem is it only download the first link, and I need to download multiple files. How can I make CefSharp download multiple files?

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean 'download multiple files from a page?'  Are you simply downloading files from a public web site?  I can think of a couple ways to do this. If you want to loop through a bunch of links, and download all files, you can setup an inventory list in Excel, like you see in the image below.

[image]

Then, run the following Macro.

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
  "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal _
    szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Sub DownloadFilefromWeb()
    Dim strSavePath As String
    Dim URL As String, ext As String
    Dim buf, ret As Long
    URL = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
    buf = Split(URL, ".")
    ext = buf(UBound(buf))
    strSavePath = "C:\Users\rshuell\Desktop\Downloads\" & "DownloadedFile." & ext
    ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, strSavePath, 0, 0)
    If ret = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Download has been succeed!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, if you just want to download one single file, run the script below.

```
Sub DownloadFileWithVBA()

Dim myURL As String
'Right-click on the link named 'Sample Address File'
'Click 'Copy Link Location'
'Paste the link below
myURL = "http://databases.about.com/library/samples/address.xls"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
WinHttpReq.Send

myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile ("C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\address.xls")
    oStream.Close

End Sub
```

This is Excel & VBA, not VB.NET, but if it helps you achieve your objective, please mark it as an answer!

Comment: Thanks @ryguy72, actually I solved it with another method. I make a script with JS and I call the function EvaluateScriptAsync.